# Добавление записи в базу данных со списком параметров JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, servlet, jdbc

У меня есть класс Person и две таблички в базе данных.

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String surname;
    List<String> phones;
}
```

Tables:

```
`phone`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `owner` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_phone` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

`person`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `surname` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT `PK_phonebook` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ALTER TABLE `phone` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_phone_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE Cascade ON UPDATE Cascade
;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 ;
```

Как мне добавить экземпляр класса `Person` с аргументом `List<String>` в базу данных, чтобы записи из этого листа попадали в табличку `phones` и при выводе подтягивались к `Person` ??

Comment: 1. JDBC
2. JPA С помощью jdbc в цикле + SQL

Comment: Код не покажешь?